# Show $u\in H^1(B(0;1/2))$ is holder continuous, where $u$ is a weak solution to $-\Delta u+cu=f$ for some $c\in L^q$ for some $3/2<q<2,$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

If $u\in H^1(B)$, $B=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^3, |x|<1/2\rbrace$ is a weak solution to $$-\Delta u+cu=f$$ for some $c\in L^q$ for some $3/2<q<2,$ and $f\in C^\infty$, then show $u$ is holder continuous in $B$

I am given the following estimate for $V\subset\subset U$ and $1<p<\infty.$ $$\|u\|_{W^{2,p}(V)}\leq C(\|\Delta u\|_{L^p(U)}+\|u\|_{L^1(U)})$$

I am not really sure how to proceed. Can anyone give any hints or insight? I am assuming I have to use the inequality and apply the sobolev embedding theorems. But again, I am unsure how.

Comment: Is any particular dimension given? Is $f$ bounded/continuous up to the boundary or just smooth?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033291/holder-continuity-using-sobolev-imbedding/).

Comment: Oh shoot, you are right it is supposed to be dimension 3. I have updated the problem. Also the estimate was given to me as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your estimate is wrong, you should double check it. I'll assume it should be $W^{2,p}$ on the left, and I'll assume $n=3$. Let $V\subset\subset U$. Note then $f\in L^p(V)$ for all $p$. Since $W^{1,2}\subset L^6(V)$ we have $u\in L^6(V)$. This implies, by the equation and the given estimate that $u\in W^{2,p}(V)$ for $p<3/2$. From the equation and the Sobolev embedding $W^{k,p}(V)\subset L^q(V)$ for $\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{k}{n}$ we get $u\in L^p(V)$ for all $p<\infty$. Then from the equation and estimate we get $u\in W^{2,q}(V),$ and since $q>3/2$ Morrey's inequality implies that $u$ is Holder continuous on $V$. Now you just need to finish it on $U$.

Comment: I dont think the estimate it wrong, but I will ask my professor tomorrow. And you are write, it was $n=3$, I have fixed the original problem.

Comment: @JLA morreys requires $q>3$ not $q>\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: @ellya Why do you say that?

Comment: @JLA because morreys requires $q>d$ rather than $q>\frac{d}{2}$

Comment: @ellya You can't really say Morrey's inequality depends on any particular $q$ without specifying the $k$...

Answer (score 0):

Morreys inequality tells us that if $u\in W^{1,p},p>n$, then $u$ is holder continuous, you need to do some kind of covering argument to extend your inequality to the whole of $U$.